# Getting last 4 months data from given date column some months data is midding

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below data

```
Record_date   ID
28-feb-2022    xyz
31-Jan-2022    ABC
30-nov-2022    jkl
31-oct-2022    dcs
```

I want to get last 3 months data from given date column. We don't have to consider the missing month.

```
Output should be:
Record_date   ID
28-feb-2022    xyz
31-Jan-2022    ABC
30-nov-2022    jkl
```

In the last 3 months Dec is missing but we have to ignore it as the data is not available. Tried many things but not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please only tag the database you are using, they all have special functions

Comment: Why November 2022, February 2022 and January 2022 and not October 2022? Surely if you want the latest 3 months then it would be November, October and February and exclude the earliest, January.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle then you can use Oralce ADD_MONTHS function and filter the data.

--- untested
-- Assumption Record_date is a date column

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
where Record_date > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data for the three months that are latest in the table, you can use:

```sql
SELECT record_date,
       id
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(Record_date, 'MM') DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rnk <= 3;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Record_date, ID) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-02-28', 'xyz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-31', 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-11-30', 'jkl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-31', 'dcs' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | RECORD_DATE | ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-11-30 00:00:00 | jkl |
> | 2022-10-31 00:00:00 | dcs |
> | 2022-02-28 00:00:00 | xyz |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=132d2cfbc6ff88fd6905ce173c2ce98c)*